# JVectormap zoom in by code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jvectormap

Hello I am using Jvectormap http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/ in my ASP.NET/C# web application.
I am using the world map. is there a way to center it and zoom it to only show africa by default? curently the whole world is showing and the user have to manualy zoom-in/adjust. can this be done by default or by code?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature at the moment. You can request it on [GitHub](https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap).