# jVectorMap custom zoom buttons

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

With [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/) is it possible to hide zoom buttons and call Zoom In/Out using their API? I've checked [the API documentation](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api-v1/) and couldn't find any methods, causing the map re-zoom.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913035/jvectormap-zoom-in-by-code

Comment: @Rubens Mariuzzo - I don't need centering or 'bring to view' functionality, I just need to hide zoom buttons and assign zoom in/out calls to my own UI element.

Comment: Looking to the project at GitHub, seems like you can actually hide the zoom buttons, but I can't find it in the docs...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Sure.

Hide the buttons:

```
$('#map').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill_en',
    zoomButtons : false
});
```

Get reference to the map:

```
map = $("#world-map-gdp").vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
```

Set the zoom level:

```
map.setScale(4);
```

Comment: not working  ....

Answer (score 23):

On a side note, you can also disable/enable zooming on scroll using

```
zoomOnScroll: false
```

Comment: I don't see this in the API but it works, where is this from?

Answer (score 5):

There's no such feature a this moment. But...

1. It seems like someone else asked for an option to hide the zoom buttons, and it is already done but seems not documented, see feature request status: https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap/pull/136.
2. To allow zoom in/out by code you could and should create a feature request via GitHub: https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap/issues/new

I strongly encourage you to create the *feature request* so the devs behind the project can actually know what are the real needs.

### Edit

Looking trough the [mentioned](https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap/pull/136) feature request, [I can see there is a parameter to hide zoom buttons](https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap/commit/b4a237631a331c603b5ec3041db762f04d9bda3d). So you will need to build your maps passing a `zoomButtons` attribute to `false`:

```
$('#map').vectorMap({
  map: 'world_mill_en',
  zoomButtons : false
});
```

The other thing you are looking for (zoom in/out via API), I think if you are really sure there's no way to do it, you *should* create an issue masked as a feature request.

### Edit 2

Months after my answer was posted, the feature got released [see that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15361688/439427).

Comment: I wish I know how to do that... I'll try my best anyway

Comment: Which version are you using? This option is from the latest commits, not sure they are in the latest release yet (but better check). But, if it is urgent, you can grab the latest development commits and test...

Comment: I've taken the latest version from the website, could you try it with the version you have and see if it works?

Comment: It is not with the latest version, it is already [developed](https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap/blob/develop/lib/world-map.js#L930) but not merged into master, currently in the [develop branch](https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap/tree/develop).

Comment: Could you push it live please?